# Do I need synchronisation when using the a char driver file handler concurrently in threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, driver

I am writing a library/API to communicate with my device driver.

```
class pcie_dev
{
public:
    pcie_dev(unsigned int bdf=0, int bar=-1);
    ~pcie_dev(void);

private:
    ssize_t m_dev_handle; // device file
};
```

The constructor `pcie_dev` opens the device file and update `m_dev_handle`.
It also creates a new thread that makes an IOCTL calls that will most of the time sleep.

```
pcie_dev::pcie_dev(unsigned int bdf, int bar)
{
    ssize_t fd;

    fd = open(DEV_FILENAME, O_RDWR | O_CLOEXEC);

    if (fd == -1) {
        throw std::runtime_error("could not open character device");
    }
    m_dev_handle = fd;

[do some stuffs]

    std::thread threadIrq(threadProcess, m_dev_handle);
};
```

The new thread function is not a method, it's a static function outside the class but in the same file.

```
static void threadProcess(ssize_t m_dev_handle)
{
  int result;
  uint32_t subIrq;
  while(1)
  {
    result = ioctl(m_dev_handle, PCIE_IOCTL_IRQ_PROCESS, (void*) NULL);
    if (result == 0) {
        printf("Process woke up\n");
    }
  }
}
```

- I am using `m_dev_handle` to do read/write/ioctl calls to the device in the main process. These calls should never go to sleep.
- I need it also in the thread function to make ioctl calls.

**Questions:**

- Do I need a synchronization mechanism for `m_dev_handle`? Synchronization is made in the driver's code to handle read/write/IOCTL calls.
- Should the thread function be a method of the class?

**To know:**

- The new thread sleeps most of the time. The driver get the thread to sleep. It wakes up only when the driver receives an interrupt.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but using the type `ssize_t` is very unusual for a "device file". File descriptors in POSIX environments are of type `int`. The type `ssize_t` is for representing *sizes* that can also be negative.

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: You don't need to worry about a data race if "Synchronization is made in the driver's code to handle read/write/IOCTL calls", your device handle itself will be copied. A data race only occurs when memory is concurrently accessed and at least one of the accessors is writing.

Comment: @Some programmer dude: The lib example comes from Intel's code. Using `ssize_t` made sense to me too but you're right, the `open()` definition uses `int`.

Comment: @George: Great, in that case no problem. At least for the data inside the driver. I guess I need to be sure to stop the thread before closing the file.